# Adding a function to Shadowbox JS library

Tags: javascript, html

I have a shadowbox gallery set up to display images. However, in addition to the next, previous, and close buttons, I would like to add an audio button in order for me to play an mp3 file that talks a little bit about each photo. Is this possible? Here's the HTML code i have for the images...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Shadowbox.init();
    window.onload = function() {
        Shadowbox.open({
            content:    'Images/Tech_trends_img/memory_capacity.png', 
            player: "img",
            title:  "Figure.1: Memory Capacity",
            gallery:    "TechTrends",
        });
    };
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="menu" style="display: none;">  
    <ul>
        <li><a rel="shadowbox[TechTrends]" href="Images/Tech_trends_img/processor_capacity.png" title="Figure.2: Processor Capacity"></a></li>      
        <li><a rel="shadowbox[TechTrends]" href="Images/Tech_trends_img/processor_capacity_2.png" title="Figure.3: Processor Capacity"></a></li>
        <li><a rel="shadowbox[TechTrends]" href="Images/Tech_trends_img/processor_performance.png" title="Figure.4: Processor Performance"></a></li>        
        <li><a rel="shadowbox[TechTrends]" href="Images/Tech_trends_img/post_1990.png" title="Figure.5: Processor Capacity Post 1990"></a></li>     
        <li><a rel="shadowbox[TechTrends]" href="Images/Tech_trends_img/processor_clk_rate.png" title="Figure.6: Processor Clock Rate">\</a></li>   
        <li><a rel="shadowbox[TechTrends]" href="Images/Tech_trends_img/physical_limits_moore.png" title="Figure.7: Physical Limits on Moore's Law"></a></li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add an audio button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function listen(){
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.currentTime = 0;
audio.play();
}
</script>

<audio preload="auto" id="audio">
  <source src="YOURAUDIOFILE.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="YOURAUDIOFILE.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio> 
<input type="button" value="Listen"  onclick="listen()">
```

Comment: Where does this go with respect to the Shadowbox functionality? in Shadwobox.js itself or in the source HTML file? Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Wherever you want the audio button to be, stick this code right there in the source HTML file. Make sure to upload the audio file in the same directory as this HTML, or just change the src to a more specific URL (example: "http://www.mywebpage.com/myaudiofile.mp3/" rather than "myaudiofile.mp3"). Hope that answers everything.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I actually want this audio button to appear within the Shadowbox "canvas", if you will. I understand that if I wanted the button on the regular html site, then this would definitely be the way to go. But I'm looking for the other way. Are you familiar with Shadowbox?

Comment: Oh I see. I have never used shadowbox, so I would not be able to help you there with 100% certainty. I did look look at the website however, and it still looks like it would go into the source code to me. You would probably be better qualified to tell though.